# Какое отличие типа данных от подтипа?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Не нашел четкого объяснения, в чем все-таки заключается разница между объявлением переменной с типом данных от объявлениея с подтипом?

В чем, например, разница, если я объявлю переменную с типом `varchar2` или переменную с подтипом, созданным от `varchar2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подтип данных, объявленый от базового типа данных (может в свою очередь быть подтипом), это своего рода синоним базового типа данных, другими словами, другое имя для базового типа данных.

Разницы в производительности или затрачиваемых ресурсах, не будет. Есть некоторые тонкости при неявном конвертировании из подтипа в его базовый тип данных и наоборот, см. документацию по ссылке ниже.

В [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-data-types.html#GUID-0E03C20F-2960-4ED9-8692-D4DCBF1F9670) действительно не очень развернуто пояснено:

> Subtypes can:
>
> - Provide compatibility with ANSI/ISO data types
> - Show the intended use of data items of that type
> - Detect out-of-range values

По моему мнению, более подходит среднее из списка, показать, с какой целью подтип будет использоватся. Например, если символьная переменная не нуждается в ограничении, не писать же всюду `varchar2 (32767)`, или ещё хуже, по принциипу: "вроде всё влезет" - `varchar2 (100)`. Или, разве должен разработчик задумаваться, что значит префикс `sys_` при объявлении переменной курсора - это что-то глобальное для всех или только для тех, кто имеет системные привилегии.

Само собой напрашивается желание создать синоним или дать псевдоним (*alias*).

Такой пример, чтобы проиллюстрировать изложенное выше:

```
declare
    subtype longVarchar is varchar2 (32767);
    subtype tennerRange is pls_integer range 1..10;
    subtype refcursor   is sys_refcursor;
    ls longvarchar := rpad ('ABC', 32767, 'X');
    tr tennerrange := 1;
    rc refcursor;   
begin 
    open rc for select length (ls) len, tr tenner from dual;
    dbms_sql.return_result (rc);
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

     LEN   TENNER
-------- --------
   32767        1
```

Comment: Добрый день. Теперь стало немого легче, спасибо Вам большое!)

Comment: Рад был помочь!

Answer (score 1):

Подтипы полезны тогда, когда вы создаёте большую программу и не уверены, что какой-то тип данных потом (в процессе разработки) не будет изменён.

Сделаете вы его скажем `varchar2(10)`. Создадите 100 переменных в 50 пакетах. А потом решите, что теперь нужен `varchar2(20)`. Менять все 100 переменных в 50 пакетах муторно и неудобно.

Поэтому, объявите тип `subtype mytype varchar(10)`, и везде используйте его. И если нужно изменить на `varchar2(20)`, то меняешь только в одном месте.

Тут вопрос: почему здесь используется ключевое слово `subtype`, а не `type`? Потому что нельзя написать `type mytype varchar(10)`, будет ошибка, т.к. `type` используется для описания новых пользовтельских типов.